# Nginx Alias route not working after adding location block

Tags: nginx, directory, routes, alias

I have configured nginx alias, the expected behaviour is whenever there is https://demo-frontend.in/dl/uurl/orr, the request it should get served from /var/www/frontend_react/build/ directory.
But instead it is getting served from the default /var/www/frontend/public directory.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/frontend/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name demo-frontend.in;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /dl {
        alias /var/www/frontend_react/build/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;


    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you please add a full example URL to your question which shows the behavior you describe?

Comment: @HolgerJust I have updated it in my question.

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks for ur explanation and solution. The issue is solved now. The solution you provided worked for me with some minor change. Instead of try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404; I used try_files $uri $uri /index.html =404; (space between $uri and /index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `alias` rules in nginx works in that the prefix defined in the location block (`/dl` in your case) is replaced with the argument (`/var/www/frontend_react/build/` in your case).

nginx then applies the `try_files` arguments and attempts to find a suitable file to serve

For your given URL, this results in the following filesystem paths being checked:

```
/var/www/frontend_react/build//uurl/orr
/var/www/frontend_react/build//uurl/orr/
```

If no valid file was found at either of these locations, nginx performs an internal redirect to

```
 https://demo-frontend.in/index.html?
```

This internal redirect then matches your `location /` block and is thus served from there.

To fix this, you likely want to adjust your try_files directive to something like:

```
location /dl/ {
  alias /var/www/frontend_react/build/;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

With that, nginx tried to find the the actual file first

```
/var/www/frontend_react/build/uurl/orr
```

and falls back to the `index.html` file if nothing servable was found

```
/var/www/frontend_react/build/uurl/orr/index.html
```

If that file still was not found, nginx then returns a 404 error.

Finally, please note that in my example, I have added a trailing slash to the location block. In your original example, you would be vulnerable to an arbitrary file read vulnerability which results in ANY file everywhere on your server to be readable by anyone with a URL such as

```
https://demo-frontend.in/dl../../../../etc/passwd
```

With alias rules, make sure to add a traling slash on either none or both of your paths.

Comment: The issue is solved now. The solution you provided worked for me with some minor change. Instead of try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404; I used try_files $uri $uri /index.html =404; (space between $uri and /index.html)

Comment: If the solution worked for you, you may consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).